# Where will I find access logs of EC2 Instance in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops, amazon-cloudtrail

I need to check who has created the instance or who has stopped/terminated/rebooted instance along with time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use AWS Cloud Trail.
Please see the documentation: [AWS CloudTrail](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/). 
You can get complete history of api calls to your account.

It is not expensive. Check pricing at: [AWS CloudTrail Pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/pricing/)

Answer (score 8):

For Linux, log files are located under the /var/log directory and its subdirectories. Within this directory there are several log files with different names and which record different types of info. Some examples include, but are not limited to:

```
/var/log/message
Contains global system messages, including the messages that are logged during system startup. Includes mail, cron, daemon, kern, auth, etc.

/var/log/auth.log
Authenication logs

/var/log/kern.log
Kernel logs

/var/log/cron.log
Crond logs
```

https://blog.logentries.com/2013/11/where-are-my-aws-logs/

Answer (score 4):

You will be able to access the details of the EC2 instance status from the console dashboard for a short period of time.

Until and unless you enable [Cloud trail](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/) , you wont be able to access the logs and activities of what has happened in the AWS console some days back.

Cloud Trail requires you to use and [S3 bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) to store the logs, and the cost you incur for Cloudtrail service is the cost of the space used to store logs in s3.